# Grails IOException out-of-range integer

Tags: grails, grails-orm, ioexception

I have a grails application in which I have a search query

```
objects = DomainObject.namedQueryMethod( param1,param2, closure)
```

This seems to be working fine normally. But for when the results of the query would be too high, I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 79737
```

Is there a solution for this?